# Why the order was not guaranteed by Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()?

Tags: java

I am using JDK/Java 19 in Windows 11 x64, IntelliJ IDEA 2022 Ultimate.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ZooInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = null;
        Runnable runnable1 = () -> System.out.println("Printing zoo inventory");
        Runnable runnable2 = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("Printing record " + i);
            }
        };
        try {
            executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            System.out.println("Begin");
            executorService.execute(runnable1);
            executorService.execute(runnable2);
            executorService.execute(runnable1);
            System.out.println("End.");
        } finally {
            if (executorService != null) {
                executorService.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }

}

// Result:

// Begin
// End.
// Printing zoo inventory
// Printing record 0
// Printing record 1
// Printing record 2
// Printing zoo inventory
```

I read page 850, book OCP Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 11 Developer - Complete Study Guide), they said

> With a single-thread executor, results are guaranteed to be executed
> sequentially.

Why the order was not guaranteed by `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` ? ("end" not at the end of line in console's result.)

Answer (score 6):

## `shutdownAndAwaitTermination` boilerplate

You neglected to wait for the executor service to complete its work.

You ignored all the boilerplate code given to you in the `shutdownAndAwaitTermination` method shown in the Javadoc for [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Add a call to that boilerplate after you submit your `Runnable` objects. Now your main thread will wait for the executor’s thread(s) to finish their tasks.

```
executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
System.out.println("Begin");
executorService.execute(runnable1);
executorService.execute(runnable2);
executorService.execute(runnable1);
shutdownAndAwaitTermination( executorService ) ;  // Block here to wait for executor service to complete its assigned tasks. 
System.out.println("End.");
```

Your original thread happened to finish its work earlier than did the thread of the executor service. That is the nature of independent threads: various threads accomplish various amounts of work in various amounts of time.

## Project Loom

[Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main) is an effort to bring new capabilities to the Java concurrency facilities.

The *structured concurrency* feature being incubated now in Java 19 might make it even easier to accomplish your goal of having several tasks performed as a group on background threads.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has *two* threads:

1. The main one, from which you invoke `executorService.execute` and all the rest.
2. The `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`'s thread

The runnables you pass to the `newSingleThreadExecutor` will indeed be run sequentially on that thread, but it doesn't mean *everything* in your program runs sequentially relative to those runnables. Your main thread will keep going, unless you somehow wait on the main thread for the tasks to complete (for example, by invoking `executorService.shutdown()` and then `awaitTermination(...)` to wait for the existing jobs to finish). You could also use `submit` rather than `execute` for each runnable; that would give you back a `Future`, which you can then call `get(...)` on to wait for it to finish (you would have to do this for each runnable. `executorService.invokeAll(...)` makes this a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Because main method is independent with `executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`